# When I make conditions within properties, Do I have to make same conditions in Custom constructor again?

Tags: c#, if-statement, struct, properties, encapsulation

My full question is:

**When I make conditions within properties, Do I have to make same conditions in Custom constructor again or I can somehow use Property Custom constructor?**

If i have code like this:

```
class Program
{
    struct Student
    {
        private int _id;
        private string _name;
        private int _age;

        public int ID // Property
        {
            get
            {
                return _id;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You cannot assign id less then 1");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    _id = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public string NAME // Property
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    _name = "No Name";
                }
                else
                {
                    _name = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public int AGE // Property
        {
            get
            {
                return _age;
            }
            set
            {
                if(value <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your age cannot be less then 1 year.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    _age = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public Student(int initID, string initName, int initAge) // Defining custom constructor
        {
            if (initID <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You cannot assign id less then 1");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(initName))
            {
                _name = "No Name";
            }

            if (initAge <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your age cannot be less then 1 year.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            _id = initID;
            _name = initName;
            _age = initAge;
        }

        public void Status() // struct member - method
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", _id);
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {_name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Age: {_age}\n");
        }


    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student s1 = new Student(1, "James", 10);
        s1.Status(); 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

As you can see I set some conditions within property like ID cannot be 0 and less then 0, but when I want to use Custom constructor, I have to make this condition again. It is only way how to do this? or is some another way?

Are even custom constructors used with encapsulation and when you have properties?

Thank you for your answers. :)

Comment: Your first problem is you're using `struct` instead of `class`.  You should have a very good reason to do so.  You rarely need to use a `struct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need to re-invent your complete logic. You can just call the properties setter in your constructor and rely on its validation-logic:

```
public Student(int initID, string initName, int initAge) // Defining custom constructor
{
    this.ID = unitID;
    this.NAME = initName;
    this.AGE = initAge;
}
```

Now when any of the parameters is wrong the properties setter will complain, no need for checking this in the constructor again.

As an aside I won´t exit the app just because of a whrong parameter. You may throw an `ArgumentException` however and catch this in the calling code or use the approach from @Mighty Badaboom with the `TryParse`-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: use `class` instead of `struct` as long as you don't have a very good reason for using `struct`.

This is a good example for using methods instead of public properties.

Short example only including age to show what I'm talking about.

```
public class Student
{
    private int _age = 1;

    public Student(int initAge)
    {
        SetAge(initAge);
    }

    public void SetAge(int age)
    {
        if (age <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your age cannot be less then 1 year.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            _age = age;
        }
    }

    public int GetAge()
    {
        return _age;
    }
}
```

I would recommend using methods for setting and getting values when you have to check things before you assign the value. It's much cleaner.

You can extend your set methods like

```
public bool TrySetAge(int age)
```

and return true or false. True when the value could be set, otherwise false.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your conditions in constructor are different there is no reason to duplicate the setter code.

```
public Student(int initID, string initName, int initAge) // Defining custom constructor
{
        ID = initID;
        NAME = initName;
        AGE = initAge;
}
```

Or you can remove constructor and use standard syntax for the public properties instead.

```
var student = new Student
{
    ID = id,
    NAME = name,
    AGE = age
};
```